# plotting 3 columns of data on 3d axes

Tags: r

I have three columns of data and would like to plot them one as the x, one as the y and one as the z co-ordinates (latitude, longitude, and height from the first point) to make a 3d surface from them.

```
  rel.height      lat     long
      15     37.02460 142.3736
    -160     37.02462 142.37323        
     355     37.02463 142.3728
       0     37.02463 142.3730
    -400     37.02470 142.3731
    -265     37.02473 142.3735
    -225     37.02475 142.3728
    -480     37.02476 142.3733
    -475     37.02477 142.3730
    -885     37.02485 142.3730
    -605     37.02486 142.3727
   -1030     37.02493 142.3731
    -725     37.02494 142.3736
   -1135     37.02498 142.3729
     380     37.02521 142.3741
     445     37.02528 142.3728
     445     37.02551 142.3728
     410     37.02551 142.3739
    -215     37.02552 142.3742
   -1670     37.02568 142.3730
    -380     37.02573 142.3744
     320     37.02577 142.3730
```

Is there a simple way to do this?

my code below somehow plots all three variables on the y and I'm not sure what it is doing on the x.
thanks

```
  wireframe(as.matrix(Sites), scales = list(arrows = FALSE, x = list(Sites$long),
  y = list(Sites$lat), z = list(Sites$rel.height)), xlab = "long", ylab = "lat",
  zlab = "height")
```

Comment: `wireframe(...)` requires a matrix where the row index will be used for x, the column index will be used for y, and the matrix cell values will be used for z, which is what you are seeing: the row index (1:20) is the x-axis, the column index ("rel.height", "lat", and "long") is the y-axis, and the values are the z-axis. Take a look at the `volcano` dataset to get a better idea of how this works. You have a set of points, not on a grid. Try `cloud(rel.height~lat*long,Sites,pch=20,cex=3)`.

Comment: thanks, but is there a way to join all the points to make a surface rather than a 3d scatterplot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above it looks like you want an *interpolated wireframe*. This can be done using the `interp(...)` function in the `akima` package. (See [this reference](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-October/116016.html).)

```
library(akima)
library(lattice)

reggrid <- interp(Sites$long,Sites$lat,Sites$rel.height,linear=T,extrap=F)
x.ticks <- round(reggrid$x[seq(1,length(reggrid$x),length=5)],5)
y.ticks <- round(reggrid$y[seq(1,length(reggrid$y),length=5)],5)
wireframe(reggrid$z, xlab="Long",ylab="Lat", zlab="Rel.Height",
          scales=list(x=list(labels=x.ticks),
                      y=list(labels=y.ticks),
                      arrows=FALSE),
          drape=T,colorkey=T)
```

[image]

Personally, I find a contour plot much more useful.

```
plot(Sites$long,Sites$lat,xlab="Longitude",ylab="Latitude")
image  (reggrid,add=TRUE)
contour(reggrid,add=TRUE)
points (Sites$long,Sites$lat,pch = 16, col="blue")
```

[image]

Finally, you might find it more useful to have a rotatable 3D surface, using the `rgl` package.

```
library(rgl)
zlim        <- range(reggrid$z,na.rm=T)
zlen        <- zlim[2] - zlim[1] + 1
color.range <- rev(rainbow(zlen))               # height color lookup table
colors      <- color.range[reggrid$z-zlim[1]+1] # assign colors to heights for each point
open3d()
persp3d(reggrid$x,reggrid$y,reggrid$z, col=colors, 
        xlab="Longitude", ylab="Latitude",zlab="Rel.Height")
```

[image]